# Transparent redirection from domain to domain

Tags: http, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have created a drupal website on an address A (`gn.christophemazuyet.com`) and my client has bought a domain name B via Viaduc (`www.petites-curiosites.com`).

Viaduc has two redirection options : standard (which generates a 301 redirection) and hidden (which creates an iframe containing the site A).
The host of site A has two redirection options : standard and URL, one is said to be transparent, the second not.

I've been struggling a bit with htaccess but I'm fearing I can't do much since Viaduc creates a 301 redirection. Could some htaccess guru help me out? My goal is to show the site A but with the domain name B and never see again `gn.christophemazuyet.com`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting a [CNAME record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record), if your hosting provider of petites-curiosites.com let's you edit the DNS settings.

In detail:

1. Set the CNAME on www.petites-curiosites.com to
   gn.christophemazuyet.com
2. Add a redirection from petites-curiosites.com to www.petites-curiosites.com with a .htaccess file (in the webroot of gn.christophemazuyet.com) like this:

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.petites-curiosites\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.petites-curiosites.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Comment: Thank you, but the CNAME settings are not available, I only have this 301 redirect which leads to a redirection loop (www.petites-curiosites.com -> gn.christophemazuyet.com -> www.petites-curiosites.com...). I guess the I think I'm going to ask my client to chose another domain name provider.

Comment: Yes, a domain provider where you cannot set any DNS related configuration is ugly. After changing the provider this solution should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your hosting provider. If you're on a dedicated IP address, then you can just set the domain name `www.petites-curiosites.com` to be an alias for gn.christophemazuyet.com and be good to go. If, on the other hand, you're on a web server that's shared between different sites distinguished by hostname, you'll either have to contact your hosting provider and see if they'll treat the `petites-curiosites.com` host as belonging to your site, or put up with the `christophemazuyet.com` domain leaking out to users regardless of what you do.

Comment: Actually the IP is shared. On the hosting provider's side as I wrote there are two options that seem to do nothing (standard and URL). What do you mean by leaking out to users? I was afraid that since the 301 redirection was done I kind of lost "petites-curiosites"...